# как сделать проверку на категорию dle

Tags: dle

Нужно в **`addnews.tpl`**, добавить такое, если выбрана категория **`X`** , то в этой категории **`X`** появляется допустим

```
{include file="billing/plugins/payhide/form.tpl"}
```

??

Comment: Это вещь из языка c#?

Comment: PHP, JAVASCRIPT, DATA LIFE ENGINE